# Converting PST time to UST TIM

Tags: apex, datetime, date

I am having a time like this which is in PST Time zone '2022-12-29 08:00:00' and I am trying to convert this into UST whose output has to be as '2022-12-29T16:00:00Z'

2022-12-29 08:00:00 (PST) --> 2022-12-29T16:00:00Z(UTC)

I tried a lot to convert this but always getting wrong conversion date. Below is how I tried

```
  String strScheduleStart = '2022-12-29T08:00:00Z'; 
  DateTime scheduleStart = (DateTime)JSON.deserialize('"' + strScheduleStart + '"', DateTime.class);
  Timezone tz = Timezone.getTimeZone('America/Los_Angeles');
  integer scheduleStartOffset = tz.getOffset(scheduleStart);
  System.debug(scheduleStart.addSeconds(-scheduleStartOffset).formatGMT('yyyy-MM-dd\'T\'HH:mm:ss\'Z\''));
```

but the output I am getting is

```
|DEBUG|2023-11-27T16:00:00Z
```

Time is looking good but date is going one month less

This is another way I tried but same output

```
  TimeZone originTimezone = Timezone.getTimeZone('America/Los_Angeles');
  TimeZone destTimezone = Timezone.getTimeZone('GMT');
  Integer offsetMillis = destTimezone.getOffset (scheduleStart) - originTimezone.getOffset (scheduleStart);
  System.debug(scheduleStart.addSeconds(offsetMillis).format('yyyy-MM-dd\'T\'HH:mm:ss\'Z\''));
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`Timezone.getOffset()`](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexref.meta/apexref/apex_methods_system_timezone.htm#apex_System_TimeZone_getOffset) returns the milliseconds, not the seconds, so you have to divide it by 1000 before adding it as seconds.

```java
String strScheduleStart = '2022-12-29T08:00:00Z';
DateTime scheduleStart = (DateTime)JSON.deserialize('"' + strScheduleStart + '"', DateTime.class);
Timezone tz = Timezone.getTimeZone('America/Los_Angeles');
Integer scheduleStartOffset = tz.getOffset(scheduleStart) / 1000;
System.debug(scheduleStart.addSeconds(-scheduleStartOffset).formatGMT('yyyy-MM-dd\'T\'HH:mm:ss\'Z\''));
```

**Beware**: as Phil noted the following part doesn't take into account Daylight Saving Time, so you shouldn't rely on it.
PST is UTC-8, so if you have the following string `'2022-12-29T08:00:00Z'` you could just replace `Z` with `-08:00` before deserializing it, this way you don't need to add the offset:

```java
String strScheduleStart = '2022-12-29T08:00:00Z';
strScheduleStart = strScheduleStart.replace('Z', '-08:00');
DateTime scheduleStart = (DateTime)JSON.deserialize('"' + strScheduleStart + '"', DateTime.class);
System.debug(scheduleStart.formatGMT('yyyy-MM-dd\'T\'HH:mm:ss\'Z\''));
```

Comment: What about DST? Hard-coding offset specs in code is a bad idea. I upvoted the first part of the answer, but I think you should caveat or remove the second part.

Comment: @PhilW, you're right, I added a warning about DST.